# Sort table rows

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

I'm trying to sort some tables using this plugin http://www.terrill.ca/sorting/. The problem I'm facing is that I cannot sort the column with the price, cause I can't think of a case for it. My table looks like this:

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th abbr="number">Products</th>
            <th abbr="strong_column">Total sum</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Card</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td><strong>20,00</strong> euro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cash</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td><strong>60,00</strong> euro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Card</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td><strong>7 000,00</strong> euro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cash</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td><strong>1 120,00</strong> euro</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried this case with JS

```
case "strong_column":
    get = function(index){  
        return getCell(index).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    };
    break;
```

Comment: What you tried with JS?

Comment: Please share the fiddle with us.

Comment: Never mind I found a solution :)

Comment: Then either share your answer by posting it as one, or delete the question.